# place two images next to each other on the latex beamer

Tags: beamer

I am trying to show two screen shots of an App in my presentation next to each other but I am getting them one below the other.

How can I get them next to each other?

[image]

**Latex code:**

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure}
\begin{document}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth, height=100px]{img/mainActivityWithAlert}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth, height=100px]{img/mainActivity}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't leave a blank line between as that's a paragraph break.

Comment: You also need to remove the space between the `minipage`s by commenting the line ending after the first. See answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A blank line is a paragraph break. Don't leave one if you want the images aligned on one line. You also don't want a space between them if they are to fit on one line, so comment the line ending after the first `minipage`.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure}
\begin{document}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth, height=100px]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth, height=100px]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: aligned images]

Comment: an alternative for the beamer class is the columns environment

Comment: @prettygully True. But this solution seemed the simplest here.